# Pass parameters to volley with the PUT method

Tags: java, android, android-volley, put

I'm using this simple code :

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        delegate.postNotificationSucced();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Log.d(TAG, ""+error.getMessage()+","+error.toString());
        delegate.postNotificationFailed((APIErrors) error);
    }
}){
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        headers.put("state", Boolean.toString(isChecked));
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError){
        APIErrors error = null;

        if(volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null){
            error = new APIErrors(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
        }
        return error;
    }
};
```

When I use the `Request.Method.GET` or `POST` instead of `PUT`, the `getParams()` method is called but not with the `PUT` method.
My problem is that my API requires a `PUT` method.

How can I pass my parameters using the `PUT` method.

### Edit :

With the `PUT` method the `getHeaders()` method is called, so can I pass my arguments through it ?

### Solution :

In my case I solved the problem changing my JsonObjecRequest to StringRequest like suggested by @ishmaelMakitla. And now I pass inside `getParams()`.

> I noticed that you are not using the response object for anything - so
>   perhaps change the request from JsonObjectRequest to a StringRequest -
>   remember that you then need to change Response.Listener()
>   to Response.Listener() and the onResponse(JSONObject response)
>   to onResponse(String response)....shout if you need further help. I
>   hope this leads to some workable solution.

The reason is that with JsonObjectRequest, parameters must be pass through the third parameters of the constructor

> jsonRequest - A JSONObject to post with the request. Null is allowed
>   and indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.

you can [read](http://afzaln.com/volley/) the doc for more informations.

Comment: I noticed that you are not using the response object for anything - so perhaps change the request from `JsonObjectRequest` to a `StringRequest` - remember that you then need to change `Response.Listener<JSONObject>()` to `Response.Listener<String>()` and the `onResponse(JSONObject response)` to `onResponse(String response)`....shout if you need further help. I hope this leads to some workable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the remark @ishmaelMakitla !

Comment: Cool - by the way, I have created a quick Gist for you that you can "plug-and-play" in your code and let me know if it helps. The [Gist is here](https://gist.github.com/ishmaelmakitla/bb48f64aa193cb8be38dd3b94ecaa0a3) - you can use the code in the Gist to replace your code above (maybe comment it out) - test it and let me know if it helps.

Comment: You previous comment my problem with JsonObjectRequest we must pass our parameter with the third argument of the JsonObjectRequest constructor, with StringRequest the getParams method is call

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "we must pass our parameter with the third argument of the JsonObjectRequest constructor" - does changing to StringReuest solve your getParams problem?

Comment: I edit my post you can look for more details.

Comment: But why do you need to include the parameter if you will pass a null (not params?) - if you MUST include it, then you need to do something like `Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
params.put("state", Boolean.toString(isChecked));
JSONObject yourQueryParameters = new JSONObject(params); JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, yourQueryParameters, ...`

Comment: yes if you use JsonObjectRequest, the only method to pass parameters is the method you show. null is acceptable if you don't want pass parameters. If you want call getParams overwrite method you must use a StringRequest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110488/discussion-between-ishmaelmakitla-and-lilrom).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using the response object for anything - you should change the request from `JsonObjectRequest` to a `StringRequest` - remember that you then need to change `Response.Listener<JSONObject>()` to `Response.Listener<String>()` and the o`nResponse(JSONObject response)` to `onResponse(String response)`.... here is [StringRequest Gist](https://gist.github.com/ishmaelmakitla/bb48f64aa193cb8be38dd3b94ecaa0a3) I created - you can simply "plug-and-play" in your code and replace the `JsonObjectRequest` code.